# XMLStreamReaderException response after Call web-services

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I've created I  JAX-WS client to call a remote web-services. The call is performed via over ssl tunnel and there is a middle proxy. This is the code of the method  call :

```
RemoteWSCredentials cred = new RemoteWSCredentials();
cred.setUserid("username");
cred.setPassword("password");
URL url = new URL("https://hostname/webservicelocation"); //the exposed url
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "ipHostnameProxy"); //set proxy properties
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "portProxy");
    try {
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL"); //instance SSLContext

        // set up a TrustManager that trusts everything
        sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {
                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {

                    return null;
                }

                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs,
                        String authType) {

                }

                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs,
                        String authType) {                        

                }
            }}, new SecureRandom());

        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(
                sslContext.getSocketFactory());

        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
            public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {

                return true;
            }
        });     
  } catch (KeyManagementException ex) {
         System.err.println("KeyManagementException: " + ex.getMessage());
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
         System.err.println("NoSuchAlgorithmException: " + ex.getMessage());
    }

RemoteWSService ws = new RemoteWSService(url);  //instance WS Service 
boolean result =   ws.exposedService(cred);
```

**The code fail at RemoteWSService ws = new RemoteWSService(url);. 
The exception reported is :**

> Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.ws.streaming.XMLStreamReaderException: XML reader error: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[14,3]
>   Message: The element type "meta" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "".

and it's cause by:

> javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[14,3]
>   Message: The element type "meta" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "".

Now i don't know where the web-services is deployed. When i try to call it on my local machine and call a test url exposed without ssl tunnel and proxy, the code work fine.

can someone help me, please?

Comment: Hi Davide. If that solved your question, you should post it as answer and accept it, so the question is recorded as answered. It is fine to answer your own questions and this may help people who get the same exception. (Also, you get some rep).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I resolved it. The error was tha I called an incomplete URL, for example: I called 'hostname/webservicelocation' ; but the complete url is 'hostname/webservicelocation/service/RemoteService' ;. I don't understand why has been caught a com.sun.xml.internal.ws.streaming.XMLStreamReaderException!!! thanks anyway to everyone!!!! bye